# Automatically ignore duplicate instances with the same attribute (before saving)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a *Tag* model with only one attribute: `:name`.

**tag.rb:**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :posts, :through => :taggings
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_users, :source => :user, :through => :subscriptions
end
```

(it has a `many-to-many` relationship with a *Post* model):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_names

  validates :title,   :presence => true,
                      :length   => { :maximum => 30 },
                      :uniqueness => true
  validates :content, :presence => true,
                      :uniqueness => true

  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings

  attr_writer :tag_names
  after_save :assign_tags

  def tag_names
    @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(' ')
  end

  private

  def assign_tags
    if @tag_names
      self.tags = @tag_names.split(" ").map do |name|
        Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you can imagine I don't want to have 2 tags with the same name. Right now, it is possible to create them. If there is a tag like this: `<Tag id=1, name=food>` and later another tag like this is created: `<Tag id=2, name=food>`. I want the second to be ignored because there is already a tag with the name food.

(Pretty much how all tag systems works)

Any suggestions in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I completely understand your problem but maybe this will be helpful for you.
    ...

```
private

def assign_tags
  return if @tag_names.blank?
  @tag_names.split(" ").each do |name|
    tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    self.tags << tag unless tags.include?(tag)
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to make the code part of my question visible.

Comment: Please check my question again.

Comment: Hey thanks I think it worked. Could you please explain what the code you added does? It seems like it is ignoring existing tags but how come it knows that they have the same name?

Comment: Tag.find_or_create_by_name return found record or new just created depends on existence of record. Then the record is added to post.tags association if the relation does not exist.

Comment: Take a look at this gem https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on maybe can be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks! but I decided to make my own Model because I need more flexibility. For instance, I need users to subscribe to tags (I'm halfway done with that).